# how to solve "value_error.jsondecode" when fetch POST?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api, jsondecodeerror

here my full code before the question,

```js
async function fetchApi() {
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: auth,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: '{"seed":"12345","Prompt":"Text prompt"}',
  }

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, options);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

i'm trying to fetch API with POST method, but I have a problem with the body

The API provider use this code by default

```
body: '{"seed":"12345","prompt":"Text prompt"}'
```

when I change with multi-line like this

```
body: {
‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ seed: "12345",
‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎prompt: "Text prompt"
}
```

the console.log show error

```
"value_error.jsondecode"
```

I want to add input.value, like this

```js
body: {
"seed" : inputSeed.value;
"Prompt" : inputPrompt.value;
}
```

but it can't be done in the inline JSON code,

maybe not the inline JSON, but the body itself why contain apostrophe, when in fact it should start with a semicolon

```json
body: {}
```

not

```json
body: '{}'
```

Comment: Neither the first snippet nor the second one is valid JSON. You need to provide more information to get a clear answer, I guess. Is that something you receive from the API or something you're sending? Maybe provide some code that you're using?

Comment: I don't know what is the method you are using to fetch the API. Maybe you didn't provide the content-type.

Please provide a minimal code to reproduce. Otherwise no one can help without knowing the your code issue.

Comment: `body: JSON.stringify({‎ seed: "12345",‎ ‎prompt: "Text prompt"})` should probably do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different problems, but multiple lines is not one of them.

- You have passed `fetch` an **object** instead of a **string of JSON**
- Property names in JSON **must** be quoted, and you have removed the quotes from around seed and prompt.

> I want to add input.value, but it can't be done in the inline JSON code,

JavaScript has [a function to convert an object to JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).